# Why in the PrintView there is no line created by CreateGraphic()

Tags: graphics, c++-cli, print-preview

the code is above. i can't understand why in the PrintView i can't see the 123456 in the PrintPreview?? i use visual studio 2012 windows forms C++

```
    private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        printPreviewDialog1->Document=printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1->Location = System::Drawing::Point( 400, 300 );
        printPreviewDialog1->ShowDialog();
        }

        private: System::Void printDocument1_PrintPage(System::Object^  sender, System::Drawing::Printing::PrintPageEventArgs^  e) {
        System::Drawing::Bitmap^ pBitmap = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap( groupBox2->ClientRectangle.Width, groupBox2->ClientRectangle.Height ); 
        groupBox2->DrawToBitmap(pBitmap, groupBox2->ClientRectangle);   
        }

   public: System::Drawing::Graphics^ g;

   private: System::Void button2_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        g = groupBox2->CreateGraphics();
        groupBox2->Refresh();
        g->RotateTransform(-90.0F);
        drawString1erPanneau="123456";
        System::Drawing::Font^ drawFont=gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle::Bold);
        SolidBrush^ drawBrush=gcnew SolidBrush(Color::FromArgb(51,153,255));
        Pen^ whitePen=gcnew Pen (Color::White);
        float x=-320.0F;
        float y1=216.0F;
        float width=70.0F;
        float height=15.0F;
        RectangleF drawRect1erPanneau=RectangleF(x,y1,width,height);
        g->DrawRectangle(whitePen, x,y1, width, height);
        g->DrawString(drawString1erPanneau,drawFont,drawBrush,drawRect1erPanneau);
        }
```

Comment: It is easy to see what goes wrong, just minimize the window and restore it again.  Never use CreateGraphics, use the groupBox2's Paint event instead.

Comment: how could i do it? i have created a paint event directly in groupBox2's Paint event, it paint all the time ... How i can call this event?? thank you very much

Comment: In fact i have simplied this programme, i want to paint a result of calcul instead of 123456 in my programme. I must at first click a button to calcul the result and then paint it in my programme. So i want to know how to call the paint event in another click button once the calcul is finished

Comment: Call groupBox2->Invalidate();